# Convert Excel Range to Collection

Tags: arrays, vb.net, collections

So, I'd like to see if there is a way to convert a two dimensional excel range into a collection.  So, it sort of goes without saying that I'd like to only keep the information in column A, the first index of the array.  I have managed to carry the ball this far...

```
Dim ExcelAp As New Excel.Application
Dim APbook As Excel.Workbook = ExcelAp.Workbooks.Open("C:\SomeWorkbook.csv")
Dim APsheet As Excel.Worksheet = APbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim myArray As Object(,) = APsheet.UsedRange.Cells.Value
```

That gets me an object array.  I can clearly see the values I'm looking to get in the first column, but I need to get that first column of values into a collection.  Is there a simple way to do this, or am I stuck with looping through the array to add the values to a collection?

Edit:  So... further complicating this... when I do try to simply loop through, grabbing 'myArray(counter, 1)' throws an `IndexOutofRangeException` and when I try in the imediate window: `Debug.Print(myArray(0, 1))` I recieve the error message `Index '-1' for dimension '0' is out of range.`  What the what?

Comment: Wouldn't that need to be myArray(0)(1) instead of myArray(0,1)?

Answer (score 0):

I actually want to comment, but I don't have enough rep, so I have to answer.

You don't want to start the loop with myArray(0, 1), instead use myArray(1, 1), because the excel array indices are 1 based and not 0.

As for converting your array to a list the only way I found was the loop.